# django password reset confirmation

Tags: html, django

I'm using the django built-in function to reset the password in case the user forgot his password.

I also created my own Html pages to make the appearance look good.

password_reset_form.html, password_reset_done.html, password_reset_confirm.html, password_reset_complete.html, and password_reset_email.html for the email.

1. the name of password_reset_form.html in my URL is "reset_password"\
2. the name of password_reset_done.html in my URL is "password_reset_done"\
3. the name of password_reset_confirm.html in my URL is "password_reset_done"\
4. the name of password_reset_complete.html in my URL is "password_reset_complete"

reset_password and password_reset_done django inbuilt templates work well with my html page created.

**The problem apprears When I clicked on the link sent to my e-mail,
I should see back to my browser my custom url page (password_reset_confirm.html) but instead i'm seeing the django built in  template ("password reset confirmation").**

I don't know where is the mistake. I have been trying to set that for 2 days now, but it's difficult to figure it out.

Can you please help me out?

**here is my setting:**

```
"""
Django settings for grouppublishingindia project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '5r0zcv0wdd2yhow_t)k)xj$c(3mnkqiww_yr0w7k+i+ii36)5v'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Inventory',
    'crispy_forms',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'import_export',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware'
]

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = "bootstrap4"

ROOT_URLCONF = 'grouppublishingindia.urls'


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS':  [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Inventory', 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'grouppublishingindia.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "contenu"

#SMTP (Simple Mail Transfert Protcole) Configuration

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '*******************'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '***************'
```

**here is my project URLs:**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from Inventory import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("",include("Inventory.urls")),
    url('Inventory/',include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),    
]
```

**here is my app URLs:**

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import reverse
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import *
from Inventory import views
from .views import index
from Inventory.views import SearchResultsView
from django.urls import path


app_name = "Inventory"

urlpatterns =[

    path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='Inventory/password_reset_form.html',
          success_url=reverse_lazy('Inventory:password_reset_done')),name="reset_password"
         ),

    path('password_reset/done/',
          auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='Inventory/password_reset_done.html'), name="password_reset_done"
         ),

    path('password_reset_confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',
          auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='Inventory/password_reset_confirm.html'),
          name="password_reset_confirm"
         ),

    path('reset_password_complete/',
          auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='Inventory/password_reset_complete.html'),
          name="password_reset_complete"
         ),
]
```

Comment: again try after renaming the url name from `password_reset_confirm` to `password_reset_confirmation`. becuase the `password_reset_comfirm` might be used as name for django's built-in url.

Comment: @AjayLingayat, Thank you for your quick response, 
I tried, but it still doesn't work

Comment: @Ajay Lingayat, 
I found the answer, by going through once again. The mistake was located in the Main URL path(project url).
I didn't put my custom html URLs in a main project url path. 
so I changed the path, then i got the result i was expected.


I mentioned where was located the mistake in case my response can help someone.
:)

Comment: @AchailletBadigra I'm having the exact same issue as you, but I don't understand your solution. Where is the main url path exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your problem is the way Django's default [template loader](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/api/#template-loaders) discovers templates. It will look in the `templates` subdirectory of each of your `INSTALLED_APPS` and *use the first* template with the specified name.
This means your app ordering is important. From the above link:

> The order of INSTALLED_APPS is significant! For example, if you want to customize the Django admin, you might choose to override the standard admin/base_site.html template, from django.contrib.admin, with your own admin/base_site.html in myproject.polls. You must then make sure that your myproject.polls comes before django.contrib.admin in INSTALLED_APPS, otherwise django.contrib.admin’s will be loaded first and yours will be ignored.

So, the solution is to move `django.contrib.admin` (which supplies the default `password_reset_*.html` templates) from the top to the bottom of your `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Inventory',
    'crispy_forms',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'import_export',
    'django.contrib.admin',
]
```

Or, depending on your taste, move your own app to the top :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tired what you suggested me but It still doesn't work. I'm still having the same django in built page showing in my browser after clicking on the link sending in my e-mail

Comment: I found the answer, by going through once again. The mistake was located in the Main URL path(project url). I didn't put my custom html URLs in a main project url path. so I changed the path, then i got the result i was expected. I mentioned where was located the mistake in case my response can help someone. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Try change your settings/TEMPLATES, but change your path with
> 'project/templates' and not 'project', 'templates'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).